# is there any plugin for auto taging with unicode support for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, unicode, tags

i found many plugin for auto tagging but none of them support Unicode text!
is there any plugin that make tag,auto from content of wordpress post that support this?
thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Well [my plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/automatic-post-tagger/) does not support UTF-8 characters but there is a workaround for latin alphabets so if your language is German, French etc. it should work just fine (however languages like Chinese, Arabic etc. are not supported).

Comment: First tnQ for ur cool plugin,but why Arabic was not supported?i hope to ur plugin support this issue in next versions :)